# Form-data post request android studio

Tags: java, android, retrofit, form-data

I am trying to create a form-data post request, tried with `@Part, @Field, @FieldMap, and @Body` but didn't work either. I tested the request through postman and it works fine but in Android Studio each time, gives the same error

```
java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Attempts

```
1.  @Multipart
    @POST("/forum/")
    Observable<Comment> postComment(
            @Part("content") RequestBody comment,
            @Part("type") RequestBody type,
            @Part("parent_id") RequestBody parent_id

    );

2.  @POST("/forum/")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Observable<Comment> postComment(
            @Field("content") String comment,
            @Field("type") String type,
            @Field("parent_id") String parent_id

    );

3.  @POST("/forum/")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Observable<Comment> postComment(
            @FieldMap Map<String, String> params
    );

4.  @POST("/forum/")
    //@Multipart
    Observable<Comment> postComment(
            @Body RequestBody body
    );
```

Though working fine on Postman:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are four parameters required by the API end and I was passing three. One parameter was missing

```
@POST("/forum/")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Observable<Comment> postComment(
            @Field("creator_id") String creator_id,
            @Field("content") String comment,
            @Field("type") String type,
            @Field("parent_id") String parent_id

    );
```